# Opening android browser from command line with local url

Tags: android

How can I open a browser intent and point it to a local url in Android?

am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///data/local_page/index.html

Doesn't work. This only seems to work with http:// prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the component part:

```
am start ... -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity ...
```

That made a local HTML file display in the browser for me, on Android 2.2 (HTC Desire) and 2.3 (Sony-Ericsson Xperia)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-t text/html`

These are the filters the browser uses:

(Not sure what `android:scheme="inline"` is for... does anyone know?)

```
<activity android:name="BrowserActivity" android:label="@string/application_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@style/BrowserTheme" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.speech.action.VOICE_SEARCH_RESULTS"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
<!--
For these schemes were not particular MIME type has been supplied, we are a good candidate.
-->
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data android:scheme="http"/>
<data android:scheme="https"/>
<data android:scheme="about"/>
<data android:scheme="javascript"/>
</intent-filter>
<!--
For these schemes where any of these particular MIME types have been supplied, we are a good candidate.
-->
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:scheme="http"/>
<data android:scheme="https"/>
<data android:scheme="inline"/>
<data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
<data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
<data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml"/>
</intent-filter>
<!-- We are also the main entry point of the browser. -->
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
<!--
The maps app is a much better experience, so it's not worth having this at all... especially for a demo! <intent-filter android:label="Map In Browser"> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address" /> </intent-filter>
-->
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data android:scheme=""/>
<data android:scheme="http"/>
<data android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SEARCH"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
```

Comment: That seems to work but it looks like it opens the page in the htmlviewer and not the browser. Clicking on the links etc. does not work.

Comment: You could try WebView instead: http://d.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: I want to use the android browser.

Comment: I guess you have to figure out if one of those intent filters works for you